# Error uploading file to IPFS: (readStream is not a readable stream or form data & source.on is not a function)

Tags: blockchain, web3js, ipfs, pinata

I am trying to upload files on ipfs using pinata but getting errors.

```
captureFile = (e) => {
  console.log(e.target.files[0]);

  if (e.target.files[0]) {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    const reader = new window.FileReader();
    
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    reader.onloadend = () => {
      
      const buffer = Buffer.from(reader.result);
      const fileName = file.name;

      console.log('File Name:', fileName);
      
    
      this.setState({ 
        
        file,
        buffer,
        fileName, 
      });
    };
  }
};
```

```
async uploadImageToIPFS(buffer, fileName) {
    try {
      const { apiKey, apiSecret } = this.state;
      const pinata = new pinataSDK(apiKey, apiSecret);
  
      const options = {
        pinataMetadata: {
          name: fileName,
        },
        pinataOptions: {
          cidVersion: 0,
        },
      };
  
      // Upload the file to IPFS using the provided buffer
      const result = await pinata.pinFileToIPFS(buffer, options);
      
      console.log(result.IpfsHash);
      console.log('IPFS Hash:', result.IpfsHash);
      return result.IpfsHash;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error uploading to IPFS:', error);
      throw error;
    }
  }
```

These are the two functions i am using the first one will capture the file and convert it into a buffer object then that buffer is passing in as an argument to a uploadImagetoIpfs function.

There are few things i have tried doing.

1. When i am passing the buffer object it is giving me this error

Error uploading to IPFS: Error: readStream is not a readable stream or form data

This error is most likely to be handle with nodejs but i am using react class component so i am bit confused about solving it this way.

2. When i am passing the file as argument

Error uploading to IPFS: TypeError: source.on is not a function

I get this error.

3. Instead of using pinFileToIPFS i used pinJSONToIPFS while passing buffer as an argument i successfully get the ipfs hash in return but when i check the hash here

https://ipfs.io/ipfs/ipfshash

i get a buffer object instead of an image.

So I am a bit confused about the right approach. I want to upload an image to ipfs and be able to see it instead of a buffer object

If there's any one would be able to help that would be great.

Thank.

Answer (score 0):

I believe part of the error is due to the SDK not being able to read what you're passing in (something we're updating) however you could try using the API instead

```js
const { Readable } = require("stream");
const FormData = require("form-data");
const axios = require("axios");
const JWT = `Bearer PASTE_YOUR_JWT`

const uploadFromBuffer = async (buffer) => {
  try {
    const stream = Readable.from(buffer);
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', stream, {
      filepath: 'FILENAME.png'
    })

    const res = await axios.post("https://api.pinata.cloud/pinning/pinFileToIPFS", data, {
      maxBodyLength: "Infinity",
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${data._boundary}`,
          Authorization: JWT
      }
    });

    console.log(res.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

uploadFromBuffer()
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for late reply.
Yes, I can solve this problem and I wanna ask a question from you that you are using automatic IPFS or manual?